# Python Tkinter TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, python-3.5, yahoo-finance

I am trying to take user input from main.py and then use that information to produce an output on runAnalytics. The problem that I am running into is that sometimes, the user input will produce a value of None (maybe null, I don't know) when the dividen_yield is not available and then my whole program will stop. It works flawlessly when there is a dividend-yield though.

main.py

```
import runAnalytics
from tkinter import *
import os
import centerWindow

loadApplication = Tk()
loadApplication.title("Stock Analytics")
loadApplication.geometry("1080x720")

label1 = Label(loadApplication, text = "Ticker")
input1 = Entry(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics = Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command=lambda: runAnalytics.run(input1))

centerWindow.center(loadApplication)


label1.pack()
input1.pack()
loadAnalytics.pack()

loadApplication.mainloop()
```

runAnalytics.py

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from tkinter import *
import os
import centerWindow

def run(input1):
    ticker = Share(input1.get())
    loadAnalytics = Tk()
    loadAnalytics.title("$" + "ticker" +  "Data")
    loadAnalytics.geometry("1080x720")
    centerWindow.center(loadAnalytics)

    ticker.refresh()

    if ticker.get_dividend_yield() is None:
        ticker.get_dividend_yield == 0

    share_price    = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Share Price: " + ticker.get_price()).pack()
    prev_open      = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Previous Open: " + ticker.get_open()).pack()
    prev_close     = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Previous CLose: " + ticker.get_prev_close()).pack()
    dividend_yield = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Dividend Yield: " + ticker.get_dividend_yield()).pack()
    year_low       = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "52 Week Low: " + ticker.get_year_low()).pack()
    year_high      = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "52 Week High: " + ticker.get_year_high()).pack()
    volume         = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Volume: " + ticker.get_volume()).pack()

    loadAnalytics.mainloop()
```

[Error]

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1550, in **call**
>               return self.func(*args)
>             File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\DataAnalytics\main.py", line 13, in 
>               loadAnalytics = Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command=lambda: runAnalytics.run(input1))
>             File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\DataAnalytics\runAnalytics.py", line 21, in run
>               dividend_yield = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Dividend Yield: " + ticker.get_dividend_yield()).pack()
>           TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your code and got a different error than you got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./main.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    loadAnalytics = Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command=lambda: runAnalytics.run(input1))
  File "/Users/Sven/temp/stackexchange/python/runAnalytics.py", line 22, in run
    dividend_yield = Label(loadAnalytics, text = "Dividend Yield: " + ticker.get_dividend_yield()).pack()
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

So I was not able to reproduce the traceback you got, but I changed your `Label` declaration in the `runAnalytics.py` file using Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) giving (*double line indentation for direct copy and paste of the snippet*):

```
    share_price    = Label(loadAnalytics,text='Share Price: {}'.format(ticker.get_price())).pack()
    prev_open      = Label(loadAnalytics,text='Previous Open: {}'.format(ticker.get_open())).pack()
    prev_close     = Label(loadAnalytics,text='Previous CLose: {}'.format(ticker.get_prev_close())).pack()
    dividend_yield = Label(loadAnalytics,text='Dividend Yield: {}'.format(ticker.get_dividend_yield())).pack()
    year_low       = Label(loadAnalytics,text='52 Week Low: {}'.format(ticker.get_year_low())).pack()
    year_high      = Label(loadAnalytics,text='52 Week High: {}'.format(ticker.get_year_high())).pack()
    volume         = Label(loadAnalytics,text='Volume: {}'.format(ticker.get_volume())).pack()
```

This made the code runnable without any errors on my system since the `.format()` statement does all type conversions to the desired string output if necessary:

[image: GUI working]

Note that there is a small typo in the Label's text which I did not fix (`CLose` should be `Close`)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked flawlessly. If you don't mind me asking, why did adding .format work? Is something compiling differently by doing that?

Comment: Also, I ran it again but deleted the brackets "{}" and it executed but nothing appeared. Why are the brackets needed? Sorry, I am just curious.

Comment: The brackets are placeholders for the variables to be filled into the string. You can also numerate or name those placeholders which is really nice when you pass more than a single variable into a string and things might become a bit messy (take a look at the docs). Unfortunately, I am not completely sure how the format mini-language is working under the hood. However, the formal specification can be found in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)